# xBest Practice to check for NullPointerException

Tags: android, validation, nullpointerexception, coding-style

To get better programming skills, I read some sources from others.
I ask myself everytime, what the best way of validation is.

[Here](https://github.com/haiwen/seadroid/blob/master/src/com/seafile/seadroid2/ui/activity/AccountsActivity.java) you will find some seafile code snippets for android. I'm wondering, why nobody will check in line 109, if ActionBar is null.
On other posts here on SO, I found something like this:

```
TextView Foo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FooBar)
```

In that post it was said, that this can result in a NullPointer or CastException. That's right. Unfortunately, even Google doesn't do this validation in its own reference.

Do you have any idea, how to deal with it? When should I check, if something is Null or not?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion

```
TextView Foo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FooBar)
```

is an example in which it's either always null or never null or CastException or no exception. So I'd not check it for null or check for that exception, since it never changes. If it runs once, it will always run ;)

I'd rather concentrate on checking for null whenever the result actually can be null or not null.